# Apple's advertising slogan

Tags: grammar, american-english

Apple has an amazing marketing/advertisement team. Their ads and presentations are always amazing. In 1997, they had an iconic "Think Different" campaign for their new slogan. Within commercials they would say "The people who are crazy enough to think they can change the world, are the ones who do."

It is one of my favorite quotes, but it sounds strange/improper (as does the slogan "Think different"). Is that sentence proper grammar?